# Resolvido - Salvar mais de uma array no Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou recebendo *arrays* vindas através de formulário e gostaria de salvá-las no banco de dados *mysql* e não estou conseguindo, poderiam me ajudar?

Segue o que estou recebendo e como gostaria que ficasse:

```
$nomemorador = $_POST['nomemorador'];
$parentesco = $_POST['parentesco'];
$nascimento = $_POST['dataNascimento'];
```

Todas a três são *arrays*! Preciso inserir no banco de dados da seguinte forma:

```
INSERT INTO moradores (nome, parentesco, nascimento) VALUES ($nomemorador, $parentesco, $nascimento)
```

O que consegui fazer, foi só percorrer uma:

`foreach ($nomemorador as $registro):echo $registro."
";endforeach;`

Continuo tentando de formas diferentes aqui e ainda não consegui isso!

Comment: Se são arrays, você terá que percorrer esse array para efetuar os inserts um a um (ou um insert múltiplo). Consegue nos apresentar qual foi a sua última tentativa e qual foi o resultado obtido?

Comment: na verdade o que eu consegui, foi só percorrer a array, não consegui unir elas para fazer o restante! foreach ($nomemorador as $registro):
    echo $registro."<br>";

endforeach;

Comment: Coloca aí na pergunta, por favor.

Comment: @MoisesPequeno você consegue fazer `INSERT` com strings? Esses valores recebidos através do `$_POST` são todos arrays?

Comment: Sim. Sim, todos são arrays!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para juntar os valores dos três arrays você pode utilizar a função `array_map`. Ela recebe como primeiro argumento uma função que será chamada para cada valor do array e retornará um novo array com todos os retornos dessa função. Permite ainda, além da função, passar quantos arrays forem necessários como argumento.

```php
<?php

$nomes = ['João', 'Maria', 'Afonso', 'Ana'];
$parentescos = ['Pai', 'Filha', 'Avô', 'Avó'];
$nascimentos = ['01/01/980', '01/02/1999', '01/03/1930', '01/04/1934'];

function format($nome, $parentesco, $nascimento) {
  return "('{$nome}', '{$parentesco}', '{$nascimento}')";
}

$valores = array_map("format", $nomes, $parentescos, $nascimentos);

print_r($valores);
/**
Array
(
    [0] => ('João', 'Pai', '01/01/980')
    [1] => ('Maria', 'Filha', '01/02/1999')
    [2] => ('Afonso', 'Avô', '01/03/1930')
    [3] => ('Ana', 'Avó', '01/04/1934')
)
*/
```

Feito isso, basta fazer um `join` e montar a sua query:

```php
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO moradores (nome, parentesco, nascimento) VALUES %s", join(', ', $valores));

echo $query;
// INSERT INTO moradores (nome, parentesco, nascimento) VALUES ('João', 'Pai', '01/01/980'), ('Maria', 'Filha', '01/02/1999'), ('Afonso', 'Avô', '01/03/1930'), ('Ana', 'Avó', '01/04/1934')
```

Comment: Este aqui funcionou! Muito obrigado! Pode me tirar uma outra dúvida? Se eu quiser colocar um valor normal, sem ser array junto eu consigo? Ex:  INSERT INTO moradores (nome, parentesco, nascimento, codigo) VALUES ('João', 'Pai', '01/01/980', '1'), ('Maria', 'Filha', '01/02/1999', '1'), ('Afonso', 'Avô', '01/03/1930', '1'), ('Ana', 'Avó', '01/04/1934', '1')

Comment: Sim, dentro da função `format` você consegue fazer isso.

Answer (score 3):

Um exemplo simples de Pivot (troca de linha por coluna), já gerando o SQL:

```
$n = ['João', 'Maria', 'Afonso', 'Ana'];
$p = ['Pai', 'Filha', 'Avô', 'Avó'];
$d = ['01/01/980', '01/02/1999', '01/03/1930', '01/04/1934'];
$q = 'INSERT INTO moradores (nome, parentesco, nascimento) VALUES ';

for ($i = 0; $i < count($n); ++$i) $q.= ($i?',':'')."('{$n[$i]}','{$p[$i]}','{$d[$i]}')";

echo $q;
```

Saída:

```
INSERT INTO moradores (nome, parentesco, nascimento) VALUES ('João','Pai','01/01/980'),
('Maria','Filha','01/02/1999'),('Afonso','Avô','01/03/1930'),('Ana','Avó','01/04/1934')
```

Veja funcionando na **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/2Mke5D)**.

**Importante:** Isto é só um pontapé inicial.

Coisas a se corrigir:

- Falta o escape apropriado das strings (o código vai quebrar com aspas no meio, e está sujeito a uma grave injeção de SQL)
- Falta o teste de array vazio
- Falta uma verificação do comprimento igual dos arrays.

No final vai ficar mais com essa cara (o exemplo é pra mysqli, tem que adaptar):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($nomes); ++$i) {
   $nome       = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $nomes[$i] );
   $parentesco = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $parentescos[$i] );
   $nascimento = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $nascimentos[$i] );

   $query .= $i?',':'';   // poe a virgula a partir do 2o item 
   $query .= "('$nome','$parentesco','$nascimento')";
}
```

Melhor que isso é fazer um PREPARE seguido dos devidos EXECUTE, evitando um monte de operação desnecessária e usando a ferramenta correta, mas aí já foge muito do que foi perguntado.